# Как сделать так, чтобы при наводке на кружок всплывал текст | svg

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, thymeleaf

[![Как сделать, чтобы было также][1]][1]

```
function createSeat(x, y, row, col) {
           const seat = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'circle');
           const group = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'g');

           seat.setAttribute('cx', x);
           seat.setAttribute('cy', y);
           seat.setAttribute('r', '7');
           seat.setAttribute('fill', 'gray');
           seat.setAttribute('data-coords', row + " " + col);

           seat.classList.add('seat');
           group.appendChild(seat);
           cinemaHall.appendChild(group);




<svg id="cinema-hall" width="1000" height="600" viewBox="0 0 1000 800" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

</svg>

> 


 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RueP3.png
```

Comment: как сделать так, чтобы было как на фотке

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Как я понимаю, вы хотите сделать tooltip как на фото https://i.stack.imgur.com/RueP3.png. Но я совсем не понимаю, что за код вы привели. Посмотреть пример tooltipа можно здесь например https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_tooltip.asp Или вот на английском SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7503183/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-create-an-html-mouseover-tool-tip есть интересно решение с атрибутом [data-tooltip]. Если нужно подсмотреть как выровнять tooltip можно здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74294620/aligning-tooltip-to-relative-parent/74294831#74294831.

Comment: Что мешает обернуть svg в div и обрабатывать событие наведения